# R extract data from XML to dataframe using XML2

Tags: r, xml-parsing, xml2

I am new to R.
Trying to parse data from an XML into a dataframe.

I need a dataframe with columns:

MAC, device_Online_status, device_onine_threshold, device_online_value.

Was able to coerce the first one.
I cannot seem to get the last three tags.

Code so far:

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)
library("stringr")

test_xml <- read_xml("test.xml")

xml_name(test_xml)
xml_name(xml_parent(test_xml))
xml_name(xml_children(test_xml))

# print the full path directory:

test_xml %>% xml_find_all( '//*') %>% xml_path()
test_xml %>% xml_find_all( '//GW_RESPONSE/*') %>% xml_path()

test_xml %>% xml_find_all('//ONLINE_STATUS/*') %>% xml_path()

# device name extracted to a vector
device_name <- test_xml %>% xml_find_all( '//GW_RESPONSE/*') %>% xml_path()
## device_name <- substr(device_name, nchar(device_name) - 12 + 1, nchar(device_name))
device_name <- str_sub(device_name, -12, -1)
```

The following snippets show me the data I want:

```
xml_find_first(test_xml, "//ONLINE_STATUS")
```

output:

```
<DEVICE_ONLINE_STATUS id="DEVICE_ONLINE_STATUS" status="FAIL" threshold="UP" value="DOWN"/>
```

Any way to get this output into a vector or a dataframe?

Thanks.

SAMPLE XML:

```
<SQV>
<RESPONSE id="RESPONSE" value="RESPONSE"><GW_RESPONSE id="GW_RESPONSE" status="" threshold="" value=""><GATEWAY_1056117CA4AE id="GATEWAY_1056117CA4AE" status="" threshold="" value=""><ONLINE_STATUS id="ONLINE_STATUS" value=""><DEVICE_ONLINE_STATUS id="DEVICE_ONLINE_STATUS" status="FAIL" threshold="UP" value="DOWN"/></ONLINE_STATUS><DEVICE_STATUS id="DEVICE_STATUS" status="FAIL" threshold="" value="FAIL"/></GATEWAY_1056117CA4AE></GW_RESPONSE></RESPONSE>
</SQV>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

xml_attrs()
and
xml_attr()

Get you to the needed data.

e.g.

xml_find_all(test_xml, "//DEVICE_ONLINE_STATUS") %>%  xml_attrs()

or

xml_find_all(test_xml, "//DEVICE_ONLINE_STATUS") %>%  xml_attr("id")